# SetimeOut interval fails with "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm getting into user scripting with tampermonkey and can't get through this error, any help would be appreciated.

I detect keys fine, space key triggers this function who will repeat itself as long as the key remains in the down position. The console writes the output normally for 30 seconds more or less and then there's a TypeError.

As per reputation-restriction, here's a screenshot:

[image]

User-Script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         TEST STUFF--------------------
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @run-at         document-start
// @include        http://*
// @include        https://*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

( function()
{
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener ( "keydown", CaptureKeyPress );
    window.addEventListener ( "keyup", CaptureKeyPress );
    var Hotkeys =
    {
        perform: 32
    };
    var HotkeyToggle = false;
    function CaptureKeyPress ( a )
    {
        if ( a.keyCode == Hotkeys.perform )
        {
            a.preventDefault();
            a.stopPropagation();
            a.cancelBubble = true;
            a.stopImmediatePropagation();

            if ( a.type == "keydown" && !HotkeyToggle )
            {
                console.clear();
                HotkeyToggle = true;
                perform();
            }

            if ( a.type == "keyup" && HotkeyToggle )
            {
                HotkeyToggle = false;
            }
        }
    }
    function perform()
    {
        if(HotkeyToggle == false) // exit
        {
            return 0
        }
        //do stuff...

        console.info("working...");
        if(HotkeyToggle == true) // continue after everything completes
        {
            setTimeout(() => {
                perform()
            }, 280);
            return 0
        }
        return 1
    }
} ) ();
```

Comment: Which line of the code you posted does the error occur on?

Comment: The error appears on the **setTimeout(() => {** if the HotkeyToggle evaluates as true. Should be line number 56

Comment: i believe your `HotkeyToggle` is null when the `perform()` is called from the `setTimeout()` function.

Comment: Use devtools to set breakpoints and debug the problem, this is the primary tool for such cases which are usually solved in a couple of seconds. The error message says that something inside perform() is null or undefined so I'm assuming you didn't post the entire code that's behind "//do stuff..."

Comment: I think this may actually be an error in the Javascript engine with recursive use of `SetTimeouts`. It seems the closure on `window` can be lost if during certain types of recursion, for instance I was redefining the function that called `SetTimeout()` several times, sometimes recursively and it seems like a memory management problem because I receive an error indicating `SetTimeout` is null like this, but only seemingly randomly.

Comment: So far using `window.SetTimeout()` has worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is either a TamperMonkey-specific issue, or a new security policy/bug in Chrome itself - I've ran into the same thing and caught it in the debugger, and none of the arguments are null/undefined; setTimeout is not overriden.

Edit: A shared trait between the userscript in question and the one that I was debugging is the "recursive" use of setTimeout. I changed it to be a `setInterval` instead, and that seems to have fixed it in my case.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a confirmed bug in Chrome:

[Reported on TM github](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/705)

[Reported on bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=961199)

Another solution which looks to work is to `.bind` the functions to `window`, eg:

```
window.clearTimeout = window.clearTimeout.bind(window);
window.clearInterval = window.clearInterval.bind(window);
window.setTimeout = window.setTimeout.bind(window);
window.setInterval = window.setInterval.bind(window);
```

The bug should be fixed in Chrome 75.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using Tampermonkey and Google Chrome. What worked for me was using `window.setTimeout` instead of `setTimeout`.